# Mirrored decoupling fermion doublers and a lattice chiral fermion / gauge theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, research-level, lattice-model, chirality, non-perturbative

**Nielsen Ninomiya Fermion-doubling problem** has known to be a challenge to construct a **chiral fermion or chiral gauge theory on the lattice**.

There is a proposed resolution to use so-called two mirrored worlds, say the original copy (called A) and a duplicated mirrored copy (called B); the two worlds A and B together are non-chiral. And adding some interactions to the mirrored copy(B) to cause the mass-gap to decouple the mirrored sector (B). Thus the left-over sector can be the desired chiral fermion / gauge theory.

This is called a **mirrored fermion decoupling appraoch**. One framework is [this model](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321386902075). There are several results against the thinkings - mostly are based on **perturbative** arguments:
[1. Absence of Chiral Fermions in the Eichten--Preskill Model-Maarten Golterman, Don Petcher, Elena Rivas](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9206010);
[2. Nondecoupling of Heavy Mirror-Fermion - Lee Lin](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9403014)'

Here is one for I found for **non-perturbative** arguments:
[3. Decoupling a Fermion Whose Mass Comes from a Yukawa Coupling: Nonperturbative Considerations, T. Banks, A. Dabholkar](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9204017)
But those are just **arguments**, not theorems or not any proofs. I read those cited papers beforehand. Some numerical attempts had fallen to see the decoupling: [4. On the decoupling of mirror fermions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6947).

Some of the papers/arguments above are about SO(10) or SU(5) non-Abelian gauge theory.

> Here instead let us take a simplest case: U(1) chiral symmetry and a 1+1D system.
>
> $\star$  My inquiry is that: **What are the SOLID objections on "there does not exist any lattice realization of 1+1D chiral fermion model with U(1) chiral symmetry, using mirrored fermion decoupling appraoch?"**

The reader (you, and of course I) should know that:
**If we just focus on 1+1D, there is no spontaneous broken global symmetry due to Coleman-Mermin-Wagner theorem. Then one needs not to worry about spontaneous break down the chiral symmetry (such as U(1)).**

ps. please feel free correct me if my understanind above has any ambiguity or error.

Comment: Check this paper "A Lattice Non-Perturbative Hamiltonian Construction of 1+1D Anomaly-Free Chiral Fermions and Bosons: on the equivalence of the anomaly matching conditions and the boundary fully gapping rules": http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7480